# custom exception (String message, Throwable cause)

Tags: java, exception

Would like to ask what will be the proper way to create a new exception object with the constructor

```
public AppException(String message, Throwable cause) {
    super(message, cause);
}
```

If i want to create a custom exception for FileNotFoundException is it right for me to write it as

```
AppException = new AppException("Load fail", FileNotFoundException);
```

Currently the syntax above returns me with an

```
error: cannot find symbol 
symbol: variable FileNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix compiler error:

```
AppException appException = new AppException("Load fail", new FileNotFoundException());
```

But! second argument should be cause of exception. This is not the case if you create a new one. You should use this if you have cause. Otherwise create second constructor with only `message` argument:

```
public AppException(String message) {
    super(message);
}
```

And call it that way:

```
new AppException("Load fail");
```

Comment: I'm supposed to create the constructors according to the class diagram provided!